# Android : AsyncTaks blocks my interface

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I got problem with my asyncTask. I have my custom USB Scanner. I want to turn it on and off with ToggleButton. Scanning works fine but asynctask completly blocks user interface. I can't do nothing. Maybe you know what can I do to make it works better ?

Here's toggleButton :

```
mScanLayout.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                    task.execute();
                if(!isChecked)
                    task.cancel(true);
            }
        });
```

Here is asynctask :

```
public class scanAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while(!isCancelled()) {
                mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter = new PartAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.part_item, mParts, mActivity,this);
                        adapter.startScanning();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And this is scanning method from adapter :

```
public void startScanning(){
        final PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        getContext().registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        UsbDevice device = null;
        while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
            device = deviceIterator.next();
            if (device.getVendorId() == 1659 && device.getProductId() == 8963) {
                this.device = device;
                usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
                break;
            }
        }
        final UsbDevice finalDevice = device;
        final UsbDevice finalDevice1 = device;
        UsbConnector.CallbackListener listener = new UsbConnector.CallbackListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(UsbConnector.Status newStatus) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "status: " + newStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String result) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };

        UsbConnector connector = new UsbConnector(getContext(), finalDevice1,listener);
        connector.run();

        UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(finalDevice);
        UsbSerialDevice serial = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(finalDevice, usbDeviceConnection);
        serial.open();
        serial.setBaudRate(57600);
        if (finalDevice1 != null) {
            connector.run();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connector.send(pal);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] received = connector.receive(36);
            if (received == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "BÄąâ€šĂ„â€¦d inicjalizacji skanera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (received != null) {
                String response = null;
                long longValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(received).getLong();
                response = Long.toHexString(longValue).toUpperCase();

                if (response.contains("DAAD0674016F6B26")) {
                    connector.send(readId);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    byte[] receivedTag = connector.receive(36);
                    if (receivedTag != null) {
                        String tag = null;
                        long tagValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(receivedTag).getLong();
                        tag = Long.toHexString(tagValue).toUpperCase();
                        if (tag.contentEquals("DAAD046F62ADA900")) {
                            startScanning();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        if (!tag.contains("DAAD046F62ADA900")) {
                            String tag2 = null;
                            long tagValue2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(receivedTag).getLong();
                            tag2 = Long.toHexString(tagValue2).toUpperCase();
                            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getContext(), notification);
                            r.play();
                            int i = 0;
                            for (Part part : mParts) {
                                if(part.getCode().contains(tag2)) {
                                    part.setScan(true);
                                    part.setScanCounter(part.getScanCounter() + 1);
                                    i++;
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                            if(i==0){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),AddActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("tag",tag2);
                                mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,2);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.plug_scanner, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Please, help.

Comment: Because even in AsyncTask, your scanning happens on 'UI thread',

Answer (score 1):

in your doInBackground you do:

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

That defeats the purpose and you do not execute on the background anymore - you are on the main-thread and so block the UI

Comment: When I delete this line I've got Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() :/ – Bartos just now   edit

Comment: yea - you need to split the things you can do on the ui-thread and the ones you cannot

Comment: So is there any chance to run this scanning in background ? Maybe not asynctask , maybe something else ?

Comment: you can scan in background - but not this way - you need to split between scan and UI work

Answer (score 1):

This Line of your code

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

Runs on UI thread you should return result in `doinbackground` and then use it in `onPostExecute` which runs on UI thread. `doInBackground` is made to run on background not on UI thread but you forcing it to run on UI thread

Comment: When I delete this line I've got Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() :/

Comment: @Bartos according to AsyncTask doinbackground runs in background u need to wrap result in single object and use that object in onPostexecute whichi automatically runs on UI thread